# Modify a group of versions for a document library or list

Tags: list, versioning

May I know if one can select a group of versions in a particular document library or list and perform modification (such as delete)? This is particular very useful if there are a lot of versions of a particular document or list item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The versioning can be configured to retain a set number of items to keep that in check. You can go into the versioning list for and individual item and delete old versions, I don't know a method for doing it for a set of items at once.

Comment: Got your point. Actually, I have such scenario that I have version 1 to 100 for a particular document and I notice that version 13 to 25, version 38 to 57 and version 74 are invalid modification that I wish to delete. I was thinking if I can delete them in 3 groups (13 to 25, 38 to 57 and 74) rather than 34 times (one by one). To me it is still OK to delete them one by one since anyway, I still need to select them if I need to delete them in 3 groups.